# ODE and absolute value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y'=\frac{y}{x}$$

Using separation of variables we get $\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dx}{x}$ which is $ |y|=|x|+c$ can we drop the absoulte value?

Comment: You should get $|y|=A|x|$ for some constant $A$. So either $y=Ax$ or $y=-Ax$ and both satisfy the original DE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm ignoring domains of definition in the following. You rather get 
$$\ln|y|=\ln|x|+k$$
so that
$$|y|=C|x|$$
where $C=e^k>0$. This gives
$$y=\pm Cx, C>0$$
which can be rewritten as
$$y=Cx, C\not=0$$
Since the function $y=0$ is trivially a solution, we actually may take $C$ to be any real number.