# Eliminating Absolute Value in the solution of a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solving this simple Cauchy problem $y' = ry$ with initial condition $y(0) = b$, the general integral is $ln|y|=rx+c$ or $|y|=e^{rx+c}=e^{c}e^{rx}= ke^{rx}$.

My question is: what are the steps to eliminate the absolute value from the solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $-y$ solves $y'=ry$ whenever $y$ solves it.

Comment: Like here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005641/ode-and-absolute-value